# Docker-compose completely ignoring my file containing environment variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    # environment:
    #   - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
    env_file: .env
    user: 1000:1000
    depends_on:
      #   - database
      - redis
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/home/ubuntu/myapp
      # - gem_cache:/usr/local/bundle/gems
      # - node_modules:/app/node_modules
    command: "tail -f /dev/null"

  redis:
    image: redis:latest

volumes:
  # gem_cache:
  db_data:
  # node_modules:
```

And here's my `.env` file:

```
REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
BUNDLE_GEMS__CONTRIBSYS__COM=XYZ:XYZ
```

And here's the beginning of my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ruby:2.5.8-buster

ARG BUNDLE_GEMS__CONTRIBSYS__COM
RUN echo "Gem creds: $BUNDLE_GEMS__CONTRIBSYS__COM"
```

For whatever reason, my `Dockerfile` is not being passed the arguments from `docker-compose.yml`. As you can see below, when I just simply tell it to echo, the results are empty:

```
redis uses an image, skipping
Building app
Sending build context to Docker daemon  631.2MB

Step 1/16 : FROM ruby:2.5.8-buster
 ---> fc5e02c64ca4
Step 2/16 : ARG BUNDLE_GEMS__CONTRIBSYS__COM
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2f1b8ded699d
Step 3/16 : RUN echo "Gem creds: $BUNDLE_GEMS__CONTRIBSYS__COM"
 ---> Running in 0b28870daba6
Gem creds: 

Removing intermediate container 0b28870daba6
 ---> 85236c218d7f
Step 4/16 : RUN groupadd --gid 1000 ubuntu
 ---> Running in 0eb5e328ff78
Removing intermediate container 0eb5e328ff78
 ---> 5cee9eafed20
Step 5/16 : RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' --uid 1000 --gid 1000 ubuntu
 ---> Running in 02ba757cd414
^CERROR: Aborting.
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try giving args on your docker-compose file?

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      args:
        BUNDLE_GEMS__CONTRIBSYS__COM=$BUNDLE_GEMS__CONTRIBSYS__COM
 
See, docker documentation:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#args
```